# Bug when using v-model causing the input field to be deselected after each keystroke

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, html-table

I have set up a table which is made up of input fields. This is made using 2 nested v-for loops from an array of objects.

The array looks like this:

```
listArr = [{ 
"$BGP-BFD-MIN-INTERVAL$": null, 
"$BGP-GROUP-NAME$": null, 
"$BGP-GROUP-NAME-v6$": null, 
"$BGP-LOCAL-IP$": null, 
"$BGP-LOCAL-IP-v6$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-DESCRIPTION$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-DESCRIPTION-v6$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-IP$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-IP-v6$": null, 
"$INT-IP&MASK$": null, 
"$INT-IP&MASK-v6$": null, 
"$INTERFACE-DESCRIPTION$": null, 
"$INTERFACE-DESCRIPTION-v6$": null, 
"$INTERFACE-NAME$": null, 
"$PEER-AS-NUM$": null, 
"$ROUTING-INSTANCE-DESCRIPTION$": null, 
"$UNIT-ID$": null, "$UNIT-ID-v6$": null, 
"$VLAN-NUMBER$": null, 
"$VLAN-NUMBER-v6$": null, 
"$VPN-NAME$": null, 
"$VPN-NUM$": null}, 
{ 
"$BGP-BFD-MIN-INTERVAL$": "", 
"$BGP-GROUP-NAME$": null, 
"$BGP-GROUP-NAME-v6$": null, 
"$BGP-LOCAL-IP$": null, 
"$BGP-LOCAL-IP-v6$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-DESCRIPTION$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-DESCRIPTION-v6$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-IP$": null, 
"$BGP-NEIGHBOUR-IP-v6$": null, 
"$INT-IP&MASK$": null, 
"$INT-IP&MASK-v6$": null, 
"$INTERFACE-DESCRIPTION$": null, 
"$INTERFACE-DESCRIPTION-v6$": null, 
"$INTERFACE-NAME$": null, 
"$PEER-AS-NUM$": null, 
"$ROUTING-INSTANCE-DESCRIPTION$": null, 
"$UNIT-ID$": null, 
"$UNIT-ID-v6$": null, 
"$VLAN-NUMBER$": null, 
"$VLAN-NUMBER-v6$": null, 
"$VPN-NAME$": null, 
"$VPN-NUM$": null}]
```

So there are two identical objects in an array together, each field needs to be filled independently. So I have made a table using like this:

```
 <table class="input-table">
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">Site</th>
                    <th v-for="(head, key) in listArr[0]" v-bind:key="head" >{{ key }}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="(thing , index) in listArr" v-bind:key="thing">
                    <td> {{index + 1}} </td>
                    <td v-for="(item , key) in listArr[index]" v-bind:key="item">
                        <input v-model="listArr[index][key]" class="input-enter" type="text">
                    </td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Since each input field was made using the v-for loop, the only way to set up 2 way data binding was to provide the v-model with two v-for variables:

```
v-model="listArr[index][key]"
```

The binding has worked correctly and when i update a field, it changes in the data model. However there is a strange bug where if i select a field and begin typing in it, the field is deselected after each keystroke. So i have to keep clicking on the field in between each letter.

I have used v-model before and this has never happened, so i can only assume its an issue related to v-model in conjunction with the v-for loops.

Any solutions would be helpful as this is a really annoying bug and makes the webtool completely useless (takes 5 mouse clicks just to type the word hello)

(Apologies if there is already a duplicate of this question... i could not find it as I already didnt know exactly how to phrase this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that in nested `v-for`, you are using value (`item`) as a `v-for` key.

This works:

```js
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <table class="input-table">
      <tr>
        <th style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">Site</th>
        <th v-for="(head, key) in listArr[0]" v-bind:key="head">{{ key }}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(thing , index) in listArr" v-bind:key="index">
        <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
        <td v-for="(item , key) in thing" v-bind:key="key"> <-- HERE!
          <input v-model="thing[key]" class="input-enter" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```